# allow jquery .on click more than once

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery function and I want to allow it to be clicked more than once. It works just in first click. What should I change?

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.b', function () {
    var input = $('<input />', {
        'type': 'text',
        'name': 'unique',
        'value': $(this).html()
    });
    $(this).parent().append(input);
    $(this).remove();
    input.focus();
});

$(document).on('blur', 'input', function () {
    $(this).parent().append($('<span />').html($(this).val()));
    $(this).remove();
});
```

span

```
<span class=b>Click</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hW3vk/89/

Comment: Why you are using `$(this).remove();`?

Comment: You `remove()` the element from the DOM, so how can it be used more than once?

Comment: check jsfiddle to understand why @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you're removing the `.b` element from the DOM, and the new span you replace it with doesn't have the `b` class on it:

```
$(document).on('click', '.b', function () {
    var $span = $(this);
    var $input = $('<input />', {
        'type': 'text',
        'name': 'unique',
        'value': $(this).html()
    });
    $span.parent().append($input);
    $span.remove();
    $input.focus();
}).on('blur', 'input', function () {
    var $label = $(this);
    $label.parent().append($('<span class="b" />').html($label.val())); // note class="b" here
    $label.remove();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hW3vk/91/)